# How to create a function to calculate values based on location and time?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I'm setting up a drop down menu that allows users to pick the time they wish to use a ski resort. 
However, I also have a drop down menu that specifies where the user is from.
Based on the time users book the resort, the resort will charge a variety of prices (3) and based on the users location, appropriate tax will be applied to the price.

How can I create a function for the "book" button that is able to calculate all three variables: Time, Location, and Tax rate ?

```
<script>
    // this is my loop variable for states //
    var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American     Samoa', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'District of Columbia', 'Federated States of Micronesia', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Guam', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Marshall Islands', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Palau', 'Pennsylvania', 'Puerto Rico', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virgin   Island', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];

    for (var s = 0; s < states.lenghth; s++); {

       console.log(states);

       for (t = 0; t <= 24; t += 1) {
          console.log(t);
       }
    }
</script>

<select>
    <option value ='00'>Choose your lift ticket time</option>
    <option value ='0'>06:00 - 12:00</option>
    <option value ='1'>12:00 - 18:00</option>
    <option value ='2'>18:00 - 24:00</option>

    </select>

<select>
    <option value ='00'>Choose your State</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<button onclick="calcPrice();">book</button>
```

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?  There are examples and tutorials for calling a function on a button click event in JavaScript, you're encouraged to start with any of those.  It looks like you've already tried to *call* the function, but you never *defined* the function.  Go back to the examples/tutorials you're using and see how they define functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a JavaScript function that takes the values from each dropdown box and then performs the desired actions.

Create a JavaScript function, and use this piece of code to receive the values from the dropdown.

```
var e = document.getElementById("id_of_drop_down").value;
```

Welcome to SO! And make sure to Google before you ask!